# MessageUI iphone sdk. assigning to 'id<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>' from incompatible type 'FlipsideViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, messageui

I'm building an iphone application which involves a video player,audio player and more in xcode 4.2 Basically the problem is the sending e-mail function(feedback). My code is fine with no errors but when i run the app it keeps giving these issues and when i click the button "feeback" for the user to sent an e-mail it crashes. Anyone can help?

the semantic issues i get:

1) warning: assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'FlipsideViewController *' [3] in this line: `mailMe.mailComposeDelegate = self;`

2)warning: incomplete implementation [-Wincomplete-implementation,3] in this line:

```
@implementation FlipsideViewController
```

here's my flipsideview.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


@class FlipsideViewController;

@protocol FlipsideViewControllerDelegate
- (void)flipsideViewControllerDidFinish:(FlipsideViewController *)controller;
@end

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)website1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)sentMail2:(id)sender;


@end
```

and my flipsideview.m (the sent mail button)

```
-(IBAction)sentMail2 {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailMe = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailMe.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
        [mailMe setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"my-email@e-mail.com",nil]];
        [mailMe setSubject:@"Feedback"];
        [mailMe setMessageBody:@"Name:(your name)., Please type your details correctly before sending the e-mail." isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailMe animated:YES];
    }
    [mailMe release];

} - (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MFMailComposeResultSent) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Sent!" message:@"Your message has been sent! \n Thank you for your feedback" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay!" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    } if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Failed" message:@"Your email has failed to send \n Please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your conforming delegate marks are in the wrong place.  Place them immediately after the part of your @interface that specifies a superclass

Comment: what do u mean? I tried putting those after the @interface but i get some errors...

Comment: I got rid of one error but still it crashes.. I made it like this:@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

Comment: Just fixed it! It doesn't crash but it stills giving me issues. anw thanks!

Comment: Delegates you want to conform to should be separated by a comma, like <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate , FlipsideViewControllerDelegate >

Comment: I did exactly what u said but i still got issues.. It works perfectly though without crashing..